# Symfony Console command that runs doctrine function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony6

I want to create console command that download REST API data to database. Now I'm using fixtures to insert it into database and i don't know how to create command that is gonna run that kind of function. Can You give me some advance how to create that kind of command?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to run the fixtures you created, run the command:

php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

Comment: I know how to run my fixtures from console, but I have to insert REST API data to my local database by console command( custom one) and idk how to make it.  Documentation shows only how to output writeline, so maybe you know how to load data into database by command diffrent than doctrine

Answer (score 0):

please try this code:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    // get remote data from external API
    $request = file_get_contents('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    $response = json_decode($request, true);
    foreach ($response as $value) {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->setTitle($value['title']);
        $post->setDescription($value['body']);
        $manager->persist($post);
    }

    $manager->flush();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Php bin/console make:command, pass entitymanager by constructor, take data from api, decode, put into object, persist, flush.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).